# video track length of Canon Legria HF M306 produced videos

Tags: video, canon, hd-video

I am having problems working with video clips produced by Canon Legria HF M306. Some tools seem to detect them as 25 fps progressive and other as 50 fps interlaced, it seems. The result is that, e.g., Blender, when it reads given .MTS file, shows video track about twice the size of its own audio track. While VLC seems to be able to handle the file well enough and plays the .MTS file at normal speed.

How can I work with this? Is this a problem in some video library? Can I improve it? Can I somehow post-process the .MTS files without re-encoding to fix this?

**EDIT1:**

It is Blender 2.63. The OS is Xubuntu 12.10, Quantal. http://shell.sh.cvut.cz/~wilx/00143.MTS is about 12MiB file that exhibits the problem in Blender.

**EDIT2:**

The zoom to blur is what did record. It was just a test video.

In both cases both mplayer and VLC say that the resulting video is 25 fps. From mplayer:

> VIDEO:  [H264]  1920x1088  24bpp  25.000 fps  6908.2 kbps (843.3
>   kbyte/s)

**EDIT3:**

Here is some interesting output from mencoder:

> Video stream: 6908.181 kbit/s  (863522 B/s)  size: 11502122 bytes 
>   13.320 secs  311 frames
>
> Audio stream:  256.000 kbit/s  (32000 B/s)  size: 198656 bytes  6.208
>   secs

Comment: Could you upload somewhere a (short) video that exhibits the problem? Also, which version of blender (and ubuntu)?

Comment: It is Blender 2.63. The OS is Xubuntu 12.10, Quantal. http://shell.sh.cvut.cz/~wilx/00143.MTS is about 12MiB file that exhibits the problem in Blender.

Comment: I'm on 12.04 and your video played differently in VLC (where it showed a mostly static picture) and mplayer (zoom to blur towards the end). My system might be too slow to play it correctly, is the camera recording at 25 or 50fps? That said, could you try `mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy -vf fixpts=fps=50 -ffourcc H264 00143.MTS -o foo.mp4` (substituting 25 for 50 if that is the correct option), and tell if the resulting `foo.mp4` plays/loads any differently?